# Which TV movie had a future all-female society facing the possible return of men?

Tags: story-identification

I saw a TV movie on the Sci-Fi Channel (or was it Lifetime?) around 2000 set in a post-male future. Women occupied all roles in society. A senator's re-election campaign ad posed her with her wife and daughter(s) to indicate her traditional family values, and genetic engineering eliminated the need for men. All the same, there existed at least one badlands encampment of men who sought re-integration and had some sympathisers amoung the women. Gender studies ensued.

Ring a bell? Thank you.

Comment: Ring a bell?  Yes.  Do I know for sure what you're thinking of?  No.  It sounds a little like ["The Weaker Sex"](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/The_Weaker_Sex), a 1995 episode of the [*Sliders*](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Sliders) series, or [*Planet Earth*](https://christopherlbennett.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/gene-roddenberrys-genesis-ii-planet-earth/), a 1974 movie (intended to be the pilot for a series).

Comment: Was my answer the right one?

Comment: Is there a porn version?

Answer (score 8):

It's a pretty common trope, but it sounds like you're referring to "[The Last Man on Planet Earth](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0193283/)"

> During a war with Afghanistan, a weapon called the "Y-bomb" was used,
>   which resulted in the deaths of 97% of the world's men. Feeling that
>   they were better off without males, the women of Earth decided to
>   outlaw men because they were too violent. 20 years later, scientist
>   Hope Chase, fearing for the future of the species, conducts a cloning
>   experiment to produce a new male of the species, whom she names Adam.
>   When Adam reaches maturity, he soon finds himself on the run from the
>   FBI, and hiding out with small rebel bands of the last remaining men.

Answer (score 1):

A similar theme: [Houston, Houston, Do You Read?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston,_Houston,_Do_You_Read%3F) is a novella by James Tiptree, Jr. (pseudonym of Alice Sheldon). It won a Nebula Award for Best Novella in 1976 and a Hugo Award for Best Novella in 1977.

It concerns a future all-female society facing the possible return of men.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing this one into the mix because the timeframe is right.  An episode  of "The New Outer Limits".  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667918/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl

However, the society seemed a little more post-apocalyptic that the questioner makes it out to be.