# Pre-1980 short story with spacemen returning to an Earth populated exclusively by women

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story from pre-1980. Spacemen return to Earth.

Only women remain, being cloned to carry on the species, and I remember that one of the men notices a lack of new chess openings.

But I especially remember that at the end, there is a line of dialogue asking something like "Who were you protecting us from?", in response to a man saying something like "But we always protected you.", when feeling threatened by the women.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Houston, Houston, Do You Read?* (1976) by James Tiptree Jr. (pseudonym of Alice Sheldon).

From [this website](https://enacademic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/502063):

> The story portrays a crew of three male astronauts launched in the author's near future (i.e., within a few decades of the story's publication date; hence, presumably late 20th or early 21st Century) on a circumsolar mission in the spaceship "Sunbird". A large solar flare leaves their craft damaged and their position in space uncertain. They make repeated attempts to contact NASA in Houston, to no avail. Soon, however, they begin to pick up strange communications on their radios. [...]
>
> The "Gloria" is an enigma to the three astronauts. Besides having an almost all-female crew, the ship seems to be very haphazard and cluttered, with plants and even animals on board. None of the technology on board seems very advanced from what they left behind in their own time, and some of the ship's functions are even powered by crew members riding stationary bikes. Their culture shock is compounded by the very cryptic and incomplete answers they are given by the "Gloria's" crew concerning the fate that has befallen Earth.
>
> Little by little, the three men start to gather clues from both observations and slips of the tongue. **They note that while crew members often refer to their "sisters," there is never any talk of husbands, boyfriends, or families back on Earth.** There are two twins on board (both oddly named Judy), yet one seems older than the other. The one male on board, named Andy, seems strangely unmasculine. Technology, and science and culture in general, seems to be relatively unadvanced considering the long period of time that has elapsed. **Even while playing chess with the "Gloria's" senior member, it is noted that only one new opening has been developed in 300 years.**
>
> Eventually, the truth is reluctantly shared with them. A plague wiped out most human life, including all the males. Only about 11,000 people survived, mostly concentrated in Australasia and a few other areas of the planet. **They reproduce by cloning, and all living humans are clones of the original 11,000 genotypes.**

---

Found by searching this site for `[story-identification] cloned Earth women` which returned, among others, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125570/98028) to [Which TV movie had a future all-female society facing the possible return of men?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125568) which turned the out *not* to be a match, but [another answer on the same question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/137231/98028) was!

> It concerns a future all-female society facing the possible return of men.

Comment: I pulled the book and checked the story. It does have the line about protecting them, about 1.5 pages from the end. +1 for the id, but I loathe this story.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I also disliked it.  The whole "man bad, woman good" trope was a bit thick for me

Comment: @PeterM The excerpt provided also seems to imply "women can't do anything properly without men around." Ick.

Comment: @Casey Maybe it's only the *"we were reduced to just 11,000 people and we are just catching up with the technology levels that we had"*.

Comment: @Casey I have/used to have a copy of that story in an anthology somewhere. From my memory, after being rescued the male crew acted rather badly towards the women (although that's partly due to the drugs surreptitiously even to them in order to reveal their "true" selves), and at the end of the story the men were destined for either sterilization and/or death because of the threat they posed to the current civilization.

Comment: @PeterM that's an excellent summary.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I was young, maybe 10-12, when I read it. As a boy, I was struck by the line about who were the women being protected from. When I thought about it, it seemed correct, that in most societies most of the protection being supplied is protection against other men. The story also implied that cloning women is not a great success either (I wasn't sure if the author meant because women never invent anything or because clones will be too similar to one another to progress). In any case, I only read it once 40 years ago, it would be interesting to read it again.

Comment: @Casey: I've read the story, and it's not so much implying that women "can't do anything properly", as that the women have less *drive* than men do, due to lower competitiveness and a more communal perspective. The men see the slow progress as damning, but the women take a "we'll get there eventually" attitude. (I'll reserve comment on whether this is less "ick".)

Comment: It seems odd that this society has cloning tech, meaning they can put DNA into egg cells, but that they couldn't combine the DNA from two egg cells into one to maintain diversity and prevent cloning degradation. It makes me think there was a period where cloning was understood as possible, but without an idea of how it would actually be done.